# Iterating a DateTimeIndex in Pandas back and forth with a pivot

Tags: python, pandas

After downloading Timeseries data from Yahoo Finance into a pandas DataFrame with DataTimeIndex as the index and while iterating dataset using for loop,I am looking for constructs to go back and forth in integer steps i.e. as below in the already constructed index of dates with 2 days gap in case of friday or 1 in other weekday.

```
for i in pd.MyDataFrame.index[1:]:
     print(MyDataFrame[i-1])  or i-2 or i+2 above
```

Thus allowing me to go back and forth after identifying a pivot row in DF.
It doesn't allow integer substraction

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position)?

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you want exactly but the following demonstrates how you can use `iloc` to achieve what you want:

```
In [206]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'row': np.arange(10), 'value':np.random.randn(10)})
df
Out[206]:
   row     value
0    0  1.183865
1    1 -0.206004
2    2 -0.251152
3    3 -0.246940
4    4 -0.898938
5    5 -0.278680
6    6 -0.658099
7    7  2.007017
8    8 -2.304950
9    9  0.599819
In [211]:

for i in range(len(df)):
    print("row", df.iloc[i]['row'], "value: ", df.iloc[i]['value'])
    if i != 0 and i%3 == 0:
        print("prev -2 row: ", df.iloc[i-2]['row'], "value: ", df.iloc[i-2]['value'])
row 0.0 value:  1.18386492781
row 1.0 value:  -0.206003776639
row 2.0 value:  -0.251152226938
row 3.0 value:  -0.246940111559
prev -2 row:  1.0 value:  -0.206003776639
row 4.0 value:  -0.898938240373
row 5.0 value:  -0.278680105208
row 6.0 value:  -0.658099354022
prev -2 row:  4.0 value:  -0.898938240373
row 7.0 value:  2.00701698585
row 8.0 value:  -2.30495039859
row 9.0 value:  0.599819374456
prev -2 row:  7.0 value:  2.00701698585
```

Comment: Thanks for the above,If i do this way then what language construct will help me to get Date from DateTimeIndex say at iloc[i-2]  Ineed both date and rowid

Comment: You mean the index value? you can access the index value via the `name` attribute so for the above you call `print("index: ", df.iloc[i].name)`